# Informative sentences from words

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have some words like "Arizona", "Jhon called smith", "Morning","jogging" ,I wanna sentence as"Jhon called smith from Arizona while jogging in morning" 
I have lot of data as above and want to create informative sentences in android. how can i do that in android.Is there any algorithm or methods available?

Comment: It is the work related to AI.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly heavily researched AI subject.  A quick and dirty way to get something basic working would be to take a "Mad Libs" approach.  Group your words into categories such as nouns, verbs, pronouns, etc.  Then just fill in the blanks with words from the relevant categories.

`The <adjective> <noun> is <verb>.`

It's hard to tell your end goal with this though for a better answer.

Comment: it will give me only one type of sentences.means for example if my location is "restaurant", "Jhon called Harry", "Evening","sitting" then i need sentence like "Jhon called harry in restaurant" i ll avoid word "sitting" there. m i right? if i ll get some more type of sentences i will appreciate. but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a field of study for machine learning and pattern recognition. The idea is to train your algorithm with sample sentences so that it learns how to build them and then becomes able to construct meaningful and human understandable sentences using what it learnt and following some patterns.

Describing you an algorithm here wouldn't work and also you implementing something without learning the theory wouldn't teach you much. It is a large field and there are many approaches.

As a good starter, I recommend readings on [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).

Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) for libraries you can use.

Comment: Can you provide me any sample code for this

Comment: Check the last sentence of my answer.